指定時間ループする処理を実装したい
Unity初心者です。
以下のように、引数で受け取った時間ループを回すメソッドを実装したいです。
一定時間待つといった処理はUniTaskで実装しているのですが、一般的にはどのような方法で実現されるのでしょうか。
よろしくおねがいします。
public void Loop(float time)
{
  while(// time経過時にfalse)
  {
    // 指定時間処理を繰り返す
  }
}


フレーム毎に処理を実行したい場合は、Update メソッドを使いますが、任意の時間毎に処理を繰り返したい場合は、Task.Delay を使用できます。
以下の ExecuteContinuously メソッドは、任意の時間間隔 (millisecondsInterval)で、任意の時間経過 (millisecondsTimeout) まで処理を継続します。
public async Task ExecuteContinuously(int millisecondsInterval, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    int elapsedTime = 0;

    while (elapsedTime < millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        // TODO: 実行したい処理
        Debug.Log("invoke!");

        await Task.Delay(millisecondsInterval).ConfigureAwait(false);
        elapsedTime += millisecondsInterval;
    }
}

ただし、ループ内で実行した処理の時間は累積されないため、タイムアウト時間は厳密な時間経過にもとづくものではないことに注意ください。
ループ内で実行したい処理に時間がかかる場合は、この方法ではタイムアウト時間を大きく超えて処理が継続されます。
ループ内で実行したい処理の実行時間を加味した実装は、以下のようになります。
public async Task ExecuteContinuously(int millisecondsTimeout, int millisecondsDelay)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new();
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        // TODO: 実行したい処理
        Debug.Log("invoke!");

        await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
}

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch で経過時間を計測し、millisecondsTimeout を超えたらループを終了します。

一定時間待つといった処理はUniTaskで実装しているのですが、一般的にはどのような方法で実現されるのでしょうか。

標準の Task を使用した例を説明しましたが、UniTask でも似たような実装になるのではないでしょうか？Unity での実装のみを考えると、UniTask の方が、Unity に最適化されているということなので、採用されている UniTask を使用した方が一般的になのかもしれません。
